# Crop center square of image using imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, thumbnails, crop, resize-crop

I am trying to create 2 cropped thumbnails (60x60 and 150x150) from a normal sized image. Everything works fine apart from the cropping, which does not work. That part is producing a thumbnail with a black line down the right side like this:

```
.............
.         ...
.         ...
.         ...
.............
```

The resizing works fine, as the end thumbnails have the correct heights of 60 and 150 (working from a landscape image as the original) but they still come out landscape.

**What I have:**

```
list($thumb_width, $thumb_height) = getimagesize($thumb_target);
if ($thumb_width > $thumb_height) { // landscape
    $thumb1_new_height = 60;
    $thumb1_new_width = floor( $thumb_width * ( $thumb1_new_height / $thumb_height ));
    $thumb1_crop_x = ceil(($thumb_width - $thumb_height) / 2);
    $thumb1_crop_y = 0;
    $thumb2_new_height = 150;
    $thumb2_new_width = floor( $thumb_width * ( $thumb2_new_height / $thumb_height ));
    $thumb2_crop_x = ceil(($thumb_width - $thumb_height) / 2);
    $thumb2_crop_y = 0;
}
else if ($thumb_width < $thumb_height){ // portrait
    $thumb1_new_width = 60;
    $thumb1_new_height = floor( $thumb_height * ( $thumb1_new_width / $thumb_width ));
    $thumb1_crop_x = 0;
    $thumb1_crop_y = ceil(($thumb_height - $thumb_width) / 2);
    $thumb2_new_width = 150;
    $thumb2_new_height = floor( $thumb_height * ( $thumb2_new_width / $thumb_width ));
    $thumb2_crop_x = 0;
    $thumb2_crop_y = ceil(($thumb_height - $thumb_width) / 2);
} else { // square
    $thumb1_new_width = 60;
    $thumb1_new_height = 60;
    $thumb1_crop_x = 0;
    $thumb1_crop_y = 0;
    $thumb2_new_width = 150;
    $thumb2_new_height = 150;
    $thumb2_crop_x = 0;
    $thumb2_crop_y = 0;
}
$thumb1_tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb1_new_width,$thumb1_new_height);
$thumb2_tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb2_new_width,$thumb2_new_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb1_tmp_img, $thumb_img, 0, 0, $thumb1_crop_x, $thumb1_crop_y, $thumb1_new_width, $thumb1_new_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb2_tmp_img, $thumb_img, 0, 0, $thumb2_crop_x, $thumb2_crop_y, $thumb2_new_width, $thumb2_new_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are going wrong in your `thumb1_tmp_img` near the end. I made this a class so I didn't have to duplicate so much like you have, but you can see the changes. See if this does it for you:

```
class ImageFactory
    {
        public  function MakeThumb($thumb_target = '', $width = 60,$height = 60,$SetFileName = false, $quality = 80)
            {
                $thumb_img  =   imagecreatefromjpeg($thumb_target);

                // size from
                list($w, $h) = getimagesize($thumb_target);

                if($w > $h) {
                        $new_height =   $height;
                        $new_width  =   floor($w * ($new_height / $h));
                        $crop_x     =   ceil(($w - $h) / 2);
                        $crop_y     =   0;
                }
                else {
                        $new_width  =   $width;
                        $new_height =   floor( $h * ( $new_width / $w ));
                        $crop_x     =   0;
                        $crop_y     =   ceil(($h - $w) / 2);
                }

                // I think this is where you are mainly going wrong
                $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

                imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $thumb_img, 0, 0, $crop_x, $crop_y, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

                if($SetFileName == false) {
                        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                        imagejpeg($tmp_img);
                }
                else
                    imagejpeg($tmp_img,$SetFileName,$quality);

                imagedestroy($tmp_img);
            }
    }

// Initiate class
$ImageMaker =   new ImageFactory();

// Here is just a test landscape sized image
$thumb_target   =   'http://media1.santabanta.com/full6/Outdoors/Landscapes/landscapes-246a.jpg';

// 60px x 60px
$ImageMaker->MakeThumb($thumb_target,60,60,'image60px.jpg');

// Here is a portrait for testing
$thumb_target   =   'http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-488-488-90/55/5543/L6HLG00Z/posters/warning-you-are-entering-a-fart-zone.jpg';

// 150px x 150px
$ImageMaker->MakeThumb($thumb_target,150,150,'image150px.jpg');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. You were right, it was the imagecreatetruecolor i was going wrong with, i put the wrong width/height in. :)

Comment: No problem! I made it as a class, just so you could see that you didn't have to duplicate all that code just to make a 150px version (or any other sized version for that matter). You can just include the class wherever you want to use the thumb maker and generate as many as you want by using the `$ImageMaker->MakeThumb($thumb_target,60,60,'image60px.jpg');`. Anyway, glad it worked!